# Select data from MySQL database and make it a value using Python

Tags: python, mysql, select, mysql-python

I am using Python 2.7 and mysqldb. I have created a table called table1 which has two fields (id, id2).

```
-id field
-234
-490
-678
-566
-569

-id2 field
-10
-29
-78
-46
-59
```

I want a script to make a row's id2 a variable(value) in order to send it with email or print it. There is a specific reason why I want it to be a value. For example, I want to select the row where id=678, and automatically get a the id2 of that row as a variable, which variable I can use in the other lines of the script.

Comment: I think you need to reformat this a bit to make it clear how this data is related.

Comment: Where is the question (as in a sentence with a question mark)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `execute` to run a MySQL `SELECT` command:

```
db.execute("SELECT id2 from my_table where id = '%s';" % user)
```

(user is the id you want to select from)

Edit: yes, you will need to follow up with `data = cursor.fetchall()`!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used data = cursor.fetchall () after the command you suggested. When I type data it gives me an answer like this [(,59)]. How can i get just the number 59 and do some math equations with it?

Comment: `data = data[0][0]` if you want to ensure you don't try to index a None object, do a `if len(data) > 1: data = data[0][0]` statement

Comment: It takes out [(,)] but the number is like this: 14L. If type data + 5 it will show me 19L which is really good. Is there any possible way we can fix it and get a clear number without L. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.execute("SELECT id2 from my_table where id='{0}';".format(user))
ids = [i[0][0] if i else None for i in cursor.fetchall()]
```